# Soma de valores Nodejs + Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express.js, mongoose

Preciso fazer a somatória dos valores armazenados em uma variável no banco.

Tenho um formulário e quero saber o valor total gerado em uma variável.

Então fiz do seguinte modo:

```
               _.each(cliente.data, function (data) {
                  for(i=0; i>=cliente.data.length; i++){
                    var valor= data.valor;

                  }
                });
```

Enquanto i >= visit.oppEY.length(meu vetor) devo somar os valores acumulados na variável valor.

Porem já tentei de diversas formas e a unica coisa que acontece é a incrementação dos valores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que você queira algo assim:

```
var valor = 0;
_.each(cliente.data, function (data) {
    valor+= Number(data.valor);
});
```

Você já está iterando sobre `cliente.data`, não precisaria de outro loop(o `for`) dentro do `each`. E também, você está re-declarando a variável `valor` dentro do loop a cada iteração, o que vai impedir de somar o valor na mesma. Declarando fora do loop o valor se mantém.

Aliás, a condição do seu `for` deveria ser `i <= cliente.data.length` e não `i >= cliente.data.length`, pois `i` iniciado em `0` sempre será menor que seu array caso haja dados nele.

Comment: Entendi. Mas o problema deste modelo que fez é o mesmo do meu. Ele não soma, apenas incrementa os valores.     Ficou assim:   Eu tinha um valor de 90.000 e outro de 300.00  = 090.000300.00. Este foi o resultado, não somou.

Comment: @Nodejs ah sim, eu ia comentar sobre isso. Tente `valor+= Number(data.valor);`.

Comment: Perfeito. Funcionou. Muito obrigada !

Comment: @Nodejs ok, de nada.